# scrapy not parsing some url characters

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this string in the href of a tag -

```
member.php?mode=&amp;g=user&start=100
```

Now my BeautifulSoup is parsing it as -

```
memberlist.php?mode=&g=user&start=100
```

which is not giving the desired page -

what is this `&amp;` and how can i fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a special string that represents an ampersand character ie "&".

EDIT: I've just tried to reproduce this using code from your [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874992/how-can-i-make-crawler-to-follow-to-parse-site-in-scrapy-using-basespider) and it  works correctly.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html_doc = """
... <html><head><title>Test HTML page</title></head>
... <p class="title"><b>Test HTML page</b></p>
...
... <p class="links">Links:
... <a href="./member.php?mode=&amp;g=user&start=100">Next</a>
... </p>
... </html>
... """

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
>>> mylinks = soup.find_all("a", text="Next")
>>> print mylinks
[<a href="./member.php?mode=&amp;g=user&amp;start=100">Next</a>]
```

What version of Beautiful Soup are you using?

Comment: its lot of messy code , jus tell me where to mention that formatter = none , then i will try that

Comment: Hmm. I think I see what you mean. Let me have another go at it.

Comment: i am using bs4 . i don't know why it came but i have manually removed that using search replace