# Writing a crawler to parse a site in scrapy using BaseSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am getting confused on how to design the architecure of crawler.

I have the search where I have

1. pagination: next page links to follow
2. a list of products on one page
3. individual links to be crawled to get the description

I have the following code:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ol[@id=\'result-set\']/li')
    items = []
    for site in sites[:2]:

        item = MyProduct()
        item['product'] = myfilter(site.select('h2/a').select("string()").extract())
        item['product_link'] = myfilter(site.select('dd[2]/').select("string()").extract())
        if  item['profile_link']:
                      request =  Request(urljoin('http://www.example.com', item['product_link']),
                      callback = self.parseItemDescription)

        request.meta['item'] = item
        return request

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
    mylinks= soup.find_all("a", text="Next")
    nextlink = mylinks[0].get('href')
    yield Request(urljoin(response.url, nextlink), callback=self.parse_page)
```

The problem is that I have two return statements: one for `request`, and one for `yield`.

In the crawl spider, I don't need to use the last `yield`, so everything was working fine, but in `BaseSpider` I have to follow links manually.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If things work using CrawlSpider, why do you want to use BaseSpider?

Comment: Well i frankly speaking, i want to use BaseSpider so that i code most of things. crawlspider does things automatically and in base Spider , i ahve to code that. Its fun as long as you are here. so QUESTION is this code works when i delete the `return request` line from above. I want to know that will my items be saved by pipeline if i remove the return statement

Answer (score 0):

As an initial pass (and based on your comment about wanting to do this yourself), I would suggest taking a look at the [CrawlSpider code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py) to get an idea of how to implement its functionality.